# Using Selenium with Chrome headless, but inspecting the headless instance makes Selenium code hang forever

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-headless

I am using Selenium with headless Chrome on Windows. (the code is C#, but hopefully it does not matter). I would like to inspect what is happening in the headless session.

When I start an automated session it writes:

```
...DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60926/devtools/browser/b4bd6eaa-b7c8-4319-8212-225097472fd9...
```

Now in a regular headful Chrome instance, I sucessfully can use Chrome DevTools remote debugging to connect to the Headless target and inspect it. To do so, I am going to chrome://inspect, clicking the Configure… button, and then enter 127.0.0.1:60926. Clicking Done and I successfully see a Remote Target appear with all its tabs and other targets listed below. Then I click inspect link below and I now have access to Chrome DevTools inspecting the remote Headless target, including a live view of the page.

My issue, that after bringing up the live view, the Selenium automating code hangs (as I see forever). Probably the inspecting live view takes the control from the automating Selenium code (should it, I mean is this the dehavior by design?), but even so, how can I give it back, and resume the Selenium automating session?

When I close the live view window, it does not help, neither closing the whole inspecting headful instance.